# Error handling by Infopath 2010 for ItemAdd cancelled by SP Event Receiver

Tags: infopath, error, error-handling

How to handle error messages in Infopath form, when a List item add event is cancelled by a Sharepoint Event Receiver? I receive an error which isn't user friendly, I would like to display a user friendly message which provides the reason why the user action was cancelled (this information is provided by the event receiver).

Comment: Have you tried using rules and validation on your form fields to make sure information is correct before allowing them to submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to send message from event receiver to InfoPath.
But you can send email to user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SharePoint Event Receiver, write a Custom Web Service.. Call that service from InfoPath form, you will have the option to communicate between InfoPath form and Service (SharePoint in short)..